# Deleting a Row in a Datatable -> DeletedRowInaccessible

Tags: c#, database, winforms, exception, ado.net

So i have this datagridview1 filled with a datatable(index 1) in a dataset(db1) and im trying to delete the currently selected row via Button.

```
private void delempl_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    db1.gettable(1).Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].Delete()
    db1.updatedb(); //sending the changes to my DB
}
```

I also write the first/lastname into 2 textboxes whenever the selection in the datagridview is changed by the user

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(){
    lname.Text = db1.gettable(1).Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index][2].ToString();
    fname.Text = db1.gettable(1).Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index][1].ToString();
}
```

Deleting the last row works fine but when i try to delete one in the middle i get an DeletedRowInaccessible Exception on:

```
lname.Text = db1.gettable(1).Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index][2].ToString();
```

I guess the moment the row gets deleted, the selection changes and triggers the dataGridView1_SelectionChanged-Event.

Any way to fix that?

Comment: On which line of the code above you get the exception?

Comment: lname.Text = db1.gettable(1).Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index][2].ToString();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A deleted row is still present in the datatable but you can't read its properties.
You should check if the CurrentRow is deleted or not

```
private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged()
{ 
    DataTable tb = db1.gettable(1);
    if(dataGridView1.CurrentRow != null && dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index != -1 && 
       tb[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index].RowState != DataRowState.Deleted)
    {
        lname.Text = tb.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index][2].ToString(); 
        fname.Text = tb.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index][1].ToString(); 
    }
}
```